# Electric astable circuit not working

Tags: astable

For school I have to build a astable circuit that stays on for 5 seconds and then turns off for 1 second. However my circuit isn't working I am do not know why here is my circuit on a bread board. The led stays on but never turns off.

The schematic can be found [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/555-timer-astable-circuit/) for the output I added 1000ohms resitor. R1=680kohms and R2=145kohms

[image: Bread board circuit]

Comment: What is the chip? Where is the schematic? Without this information we cannot help you.

Comment: You *need* to add a schematic, otherwise we are unable to say anything useful.

Comment: I have added the schematic sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Your capacitor looks way too small to give you a period in seconds.  What size is it?

Comment: They are both 10nF

Comment: Using the calculator on the page you provided, you get a frequency of 148Hz with a 10nF capacitor.  Try something like a 10uF or 100uF to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have pin 2 connected to ground and pin 1 floating.  Move the black ground jumper from pin 2 to pin 1.  Because of this error, the 555 might have been damaged.  You should replace it after you correct the circuit.

The capacitor at pin 6 is 10 nF.  Increase this to 10 uF.

Recalculate R1.